# Best practice to handle nested object relations of the same kind (parent:child) in Obj-C or Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8

I am working on an app that will consume JSON thru AFNetworking and use Mantle to parse the JSON to actual swift model objects.

I have one particular case where a "Category" model is related to another "Category" (parent). Meaning that a category can have an infinite number of parent's or children of the same Type. It's a tree of categories and sub categories. So once can traverse the models as:

**category->children->children, etc..** 
*Or* 
 **category->parent->parent, etc... Children are subcategories.**

What would the best or recommended practice be to make this relationships? I don't want to duplicate objects.

The jSON i am consuming is :

```
{  
   "categories":[  
      {  
         "id":1,
         "name":"myCategory",
         "order":1,
         "parent":""
      },
      {  
         "id":2,
         "name":"MyParentCateg",
         "order":2,
         "parent":{  
            "id":1
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

I am inclined to think that I should load all the categories and parse them to objects in an Array, and then go thru the array once all data is loaded and make the relationships then, so that the relationships are pointer's to actual objects.. Thus I don't have to load the same object twice.

What would you recommend to do?

ANY Suggestion or experience you want to share, SUPER WELCOMED!
Thanks in advance!

PS: I do have access to manipulate the response from the server, I could have the server hand me the JSON as nested categories instead of all the categories as root and relationships as ID's only. Whatever it's best for performance and recommendations.

Comment: Are you saying that you have potentially infinite children depth like a directory structure in a file system, or do you have circular relationships where an object's child eventually loops back around to being its parent? (grandparent -> parent -> child -> grandparent). Or do you have multiple parents with the same children?

Comment: Parent objects are guaranteed to be preceding its children in JSON array?

Comment: @drewag 1) it's like a file structure, no circular relationship. It's like a waterfall.

Comment: @rintaro Yes... Always parent and then children... Children may only have a unique parent and parent may only have a unique children. However, it would be nice to know how to handle things when multiple parents can reference the same children..

Comment: Anyone? How would you handle this?